# How to display unique answer for each user input in vim

Tags: unix, vim, vi

Using a case structure, display a unique answer for each colour. (Red, Yellow, Green, Blue, 
White, Black) Make sure to have a default answer in case none of the above colours are selected.

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: Do *your* homework *yourself*.

Comment: @romainl I am trying too, but i'm new to all this so i need help.

Comment: @zplesivcak I am trying to make something in vim, like Ask the user for their favourite colour and save it to a variable(i already did that) using                                                                                                                   read –p “What is your favourite colour?” colour
      echo $colour
Now my question is how to give unique answer like i asked before.

Comment: read -p has nothing to do with Vim and sounds like your are doing something in shell

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt i started this about a week ago this is all new to me i just started learning the basics of it all. So i don't really know much

Answer (score 1):

For multiple choice, there's `confirm()` in Vimscript. You can also use `input()` for arbitrary, typed input.

#### Demo

```
let answer = confirm("Your favorite color:", "Red\nYellow\nGreen\nBlue\nWhite\nBlack")
if answer == 1
    echomsg 'I like red, too'
elseif answer == 2
    echomsg 'I think of lemons'
else
    echomsg 'Aha.'
endif
```